# Bootstrap site looks fine in browser, but divs won't render correctly in mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a multi-row, multi-column site using Bootstrap. The site looks great in a regular browser, but when I resize it for mobile, the divs misalign, stack on top of one another, the content inside disappears, or the divs flatten so much to where you can't see the image. How do I prevent this odd resizing of divs in large/medium size screens, but stack proportionally on a small screen?

Here's one of my rows:

```
<div class="row row1">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-5 row1-topleft">
                <div class="inside-index">
                    <h2>one header</h2>
                    <p>content</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-7 row1-topright">
                <div class="inside-index-img">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/900x1200">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end  row1 -->
```

and the CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
div {
    height: 100%;
}
.row1 {
    height: 120%;
}
```

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hcgriggs/jkLjnt0d/4/) with the whole site and problem recreated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly this what you get:
[image]
and this is what you want:
[image]

Solution you are looking for is putting image as a background and using css property `background-size:cover` to fit size of the column.

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/jkLjnt0d/7/

Comment: Thanks @Kinga! This is really helpful. However, I'm mostly confused as to why the divs don't resize proportionally (i.e., if the div is a square in the browser, in mobile it flattens to a rectangle) and why images in col-xs-12 don't resize to fit the height and width of the div in mobile. Instead there's a large margin to the side of the image. Would background-size:cover fix that too?